# How to access variables in ScriptComponent in a DataFlow task and assign to a local variable

Tags: ssis, script-component

I am trying to access the variable `RowCount`. However, I can't do :
since its assign value as `0` to row count even if have a result set

```
var rowCount=this.Variables.RowCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you trying to access this variable, and are you trying to update it?  SSIS variables can only be written to in the `PostExecute` method.  To do this, start by adding the variable to the `ReadWriteVariables` field of the script component editor, then you can access this as done below.

Your variable is named `rowCount`.  Are you looking to return the number of rows that go through the Data Flow Task?  A Script Component is called once for each record in a Data Flow Task.  To get the total number of records, use **Row Count** transformation instead and assign the variable to the result of this.

```
int rowCount;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    //get variable value before processing rows.
    rowCount = Variables.RowCount;
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    //update variable after records have been procssed
    Variables.RowCount = rowCount;
}
```